# heroku not working /heroku/commands/pgbackups.rb:9:in `<class:Pgbackups>': uninitialized constant Heroku::Command::Pgbackups::Help (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

If i tipe heroku in console, i become this:

`` ~onemore~>heroku

/home/koli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@onemore/gems/heroku-1.13.1/lib/heroku/commands/pgbackups.rb:9:in `': uninitialized constant Heroku::Command::Pgbackups::Help (NameError) ``

```
from /home/koli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@onemore/gems/heroku-1.13.1/lib/heroku/commands/pgbackups.rb:6:in `<module:Command>'
from /home/koli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@onemore/gems/heroku-1.13.1/lib/heroku/commands/pgbackups.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from /home/koli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@onemore/gems/heroku-1.13.1/lib/heroku/command.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/koli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@onemore/gems/heroku-1.13.1/lib/heroku/command.rb:5:in `each'
from /home/koli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@onemore/gems/heroku-1.13.1/lib/heroku/command.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from /home/koli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@onemore/gems/heroku-1.13.1/bin/heroku:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/koli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@onemore/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
from /home/koli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@onemore/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

I installed rvm, then ruby 1.9.2, then rails 3.0.1. Then i had make a new project with rails new onemore.
I had make a gemset for it. After that, i installed rails 3.0.1 in that gemset too, and then bundle install. After that i installed heroku with gem install heroku.
I have no idea how to fix this problem... I reinstalled everything, but the same...
Any idea, or hint?

Thanks:Koli

Comment: Same Issue here but No Result Yet Got !!!

Comment: Koli, Did you got the answer ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you enabled the pgbackup addon in Heroku? Something like

`$ sudo gem install heroku`

`$ heroku addons:add pgbackups:basic`

`$ heroku pgbackups:capture`